# Key Sensor | KEY + SHIFT ( with First Modifier )

Tags: game-engine, logic-bricks

Good Morning

I try to use the first and second modifier in the key sensor, but I can't find more information or examples of this, example

*I try a simple combination in the pic but it does not work*

<kbd>S</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd> and/or <kbd>S</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd>

somebody can make a example of this, please

**PLEASE IN LOGIC BRICKS**
thanks

[image: **Key Sensor + First Modifuer**]
[image: **what i more i need do?**]

***REFERENCE***
[(Blender Game Engine) Walk and Run cycle sound problems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTN3v.png)

Comment: What exactly is not working as expected?

Comment: You noticed that the second Key-Sensor isn't connected to the Controller?

Comment: I want to use the S key to move forward and when you press SHIFT and S back up.
yes, but I was not testing right and left so I do not bother to connect it, I concentrate on knowing what the hell then work First Modifier & Second Modifier

Comment: @Quacksilber sorry, correction i disconnect the 2nd sensor, to try make work de 4th sensor with S + SHIFT LEFT but i lost, not work with i connect the two sensor, maybe i need something to control wen you go forward and backward

Comment: I don't know, if I understood you correctly. Did you mean that if you press "s", it moves and if you then press "shift", the motion stops? This would be because both sensors would then be active at the same time and eliminate themselves. (0.10 + -0.10 = 0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keyboard sensors allow to sense up to three keys being pressed at the same time.

It is the same behavior as three keyboard sensor's connected to a single AND controller.

There are some things to know about:
- Keyboards can deal with 3 pressed keys -> but more keys might not sensed (this is an hardware/OS issue)
- Keyboard sensors sensing one of the (already sensed) keys will still measure the single key press. It will not automatically ignore the single key because a modifier of another keyboard sensor is pressed.

## Exclusive events

When you want to deal with  +  and  differently you need to describe it explicitly:

- AND
- AND not

The first condition can be sensed with the modifiers as you do already. Alternative you can use two keyboard sensors with AND.

The second expression requires two keyboard sensors:

-> Keyboard sensor sense

-> Keyboard sensor sense  [inverted]

combined with AND

[image]

or

-> Keyboard sensor "A" sense

-> Keyboard sensor "Shift" sense

(both positive)

combined with expression controller: "A and not Shift"

The last option can be used to reduce the number of involved sensors:
[image]

Comment: Assalam alaykum warahamatullah wabarakatu 
ok i understand more less, **but and what are the first and second modifier boxes ???**

Comment: **but and what are the first and second modifier boxes ???**, why have a 1 brick for Left shift separate of A, and why have a brick for **A & Left Shift (in the first modifier)**

Comment: As said, the modifier option is a shortcut to two keyboard sensors combined with AND. You measure -> "shift+A" are pressed at the same time. It does not measure "not shift + A"

Comment: You are right, not being able to detect combinations of more keys pressed simultaneously,yes it's a hardware problem, I had already asked myself before because it could not,but someone made fun of me because I asked that, so I left it for peace, but I see that there are more people who think like me, you should be able to press unlimited simultaneous key combinations, or minimum for those that reach your fingers and toes

Comment: how many times i can combine Left Shift with other keys, after using it with shift A, as in the example?

Comment: Guarantied is 3 keys. So you can get <shift> + 2 other keys. On my keyboard I can have some combination up to 10 keys. But other combinations are just 3. <shift>, <ctrl> and <alt> are usually meant as "modifiers" so I think combinations with them are more than three. Be aware this might be different on other keyboards.